# Journal abbreviation mapping mystery

Tags: biblatex, biber

Here is my tex document:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear-icomp,
citestyle=authoryear-icomp,
uniquename=false,
uniquelist=false, 
firstinits=true, 
maxbibnames=5,
minbibnames=5, 
maxcitenames=2,
mincitenames=1, 
sorting=ynt, 
url=false, 
isbn=false, 
eprint=false, 
doi=false, 
dashed=false, 
natbib=true,
ibidtracker=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@ARTICLE{Rehfeldt2006a,
  author = {Rehfeldt, Gerald E. and Crookston, Nicholas L. and Warwell, Marcus
    V. and Evans, Jeffrey S.},
  title = {Empirical analyses of plant climate relationships for the western
    United States},
  journal = {International Journal of Plant Sciences},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {167},
  pages = {1123--1150},
  number = {6},
  url = {http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/507711}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{Rehfeldt2006a} demonstrated how to calculate certain environmental variables.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The mapping file is `~/.biber.conf`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config>
  <sourcemap>
   <maps datatype="bibtex">

     <map map_overwrite="1">
      <map_step map_field_source="journal"
       map_match = "International Journal of Plant Sciences"
       map_replace = "Int. J. Plant Sci."/>
     </map>


   </maps>
  </sourcemap>
 </config>
```

When bibliography is printed, the journal name does not get abbreviated.  It is also printed in a strange fashion as follows:

```
International Journal of Plant Science.s
```

instead of `Int. J. Plant Sci.`

I have 60-65 other name mapping which work perfectly fine, except for this one.  I have spent more than an hour looking closely if I made any mistake anywhere, but I can't seem to find anything.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Just to add to the mystery, It works perfectly for me. Did you actually try this MWE? Nothing more in biber.conf? Btw, I put `biber.conf` (without trailing dot) in my working directory, instead of my home dir, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: I can confirm it works as expected.

Comment: Now this is strange.  The MWE works for me as well.  But as soon as I replace the MWE biber configuration with the real .biber.conf, things stop working again.  I have gone through the entire file line by line, made sure the code on top and bottom remains unaltered and all mapping entries are syntactically correct.  What is most strange is that it happens with only one journal name mapping.  All other names are mapped correctly.

Comment: Can you post the full biber.conf? Or put it somewhere we can see it?

Comment: On a whim, I decided to move the mapping for this journal from its location in the middle of .biber.conf to the beginning of the file.   And that solved the problem.  I have absolutely no idea what the problem was and how what I did helped.  Perhaps someone has an insight.